# convert table cells to table rows in Iphone screen

Tags: html, css, ios, media-queries

i have a scenerio where i have a table, inside this table is one table row (tr) and this row contains 3 table cells (td's). When browser or device size become less than 768px these td's are displayed like a row,so user do not need to scroll x-axis. Now i have issue on iphone Safari and Chrome browsers where these td's are not displayed as a row. i am using following Code.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) {
 .tabular_structure > td {
    display:table-row !important;
  }
  }

 .table-left{
width:20%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
.table-center{
width:60%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
.table-right{
width:20%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr class="tabular_structure">
          <td class="table-left">
            <table class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-10 ">
              <tbody>
                <tr style="height:auto; width:100%;">
                  <td style="border-top:0px;">
                    
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div>
 <h5 class="customText">An Initiative</h5><br></div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="offsetClass" style="display: block">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-6 col-lg-6">
                            <p class="customText" style="text-align:center">Sun Rise</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-6 col-lg-6 pull-right">
                            <p class="customText" style="text-align:center">Sun Set</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-10">
                    
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </td>
        <td class="table-center">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr  class="green-border">
                <p>Second cell</p>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
<td class="table-right">
<p>Third Cell
</p>
</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: One question... why do you use table as layout?

Comment: i thought it will be easy to display content in table. But now i am caught up in iphone's scenerio, need some help

Comment: it's not a good choice to use table for render layout...

Comment: but its working good on Android and all other screens, only iphone is giving issues, although i resolved my issue by removing tables but i am curious to know what was the issue